# Using variables off a prefab script with multiple instances

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a unity game in 2d. The idea of game is 2D Dots (Horses) racing around the racecourse. I have a int variable called horsePos (Horse Position as in First, Second, Third). This works. What I am trying to do is see which horse is in front whether it be Horse (the original prefab) or the instantiated version of the prefab (Horse (1)).

So I am using an external script that is an empty gameObject called Game Handler. This is my reference to the gameObjects.

```
        horseOne = GameObject.Find("Horse");
        horseTwo = GameObject.Find("Horse (1)");
```

When trying the following code in update it gives me the error "'GameObject' does not contain a definition for 'horsePos' and no accessible extension method 'horsePos' accepting a first argument of type 'GameObject' could be found"

```
if (horseOne.horsePos < horseTwo.horsePos)
        {
            Debug.Log("horse 1 infront");
        }
```

I have tried using  however due me targeting more than 1 instance of that particular script I don't believe this will work so I will need to target the gameObject then the script of that specific gameObject.

Any help will be appreciated and if any additional information i'll provide it.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have tried using <GetComponent> is what the last section is meant to say*

Comment: use GetComponent on each gameObject to get the script reference.  ie.  `var horse1 = horseOne.GetComponent<Horse>();`

Comment: Horse being the script right?

Comment: Yeah, whatever the script is named that has the `horsePos` variable declared.

Comment: I have implemented this and still giving the same error, I'm not sure but could it be because the gameObject isn't getting found until I start the game? How would it know that the "GameObject" doesn't have the property horsePos if I'm not using the .Find until it starts the game? (I am using .Find and .GetComponents in void start)

Comment: The error you presented in the question is a compiler error.  This happens outside of the game, therefore it cannot be a result of using Find.  Make sure you are accessing the variable from the script reference and not a GameObject reference.  `var horseGO = Find("Horse");  var horseScript = horseGO.GetComponent<Horse>();  var pos = horseScript.horsePos;`

Answer (score 0):

Never use GameObject.Find. It is just a bad practice. For such use cases, use inspector references for prefabs and store your instantiated objects in variables.
Change your code like this:

```
public class GameHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Horse horsePrefab;

    private Horse horseOne;
    private Horse horseTwo;

    private void Start()
    {
        SpawnHorses();
    }

    public void SpawnHorses()
    {
        horseOne = Instantiate(horsePrefab);
        horseTwo = Instantiate(horsePrefab);
    }

    private void CheckHorses()
    {
        if (horseOne.horsePos < horseTwo.horsePos)
        {
            Debug.Log("horse 1 infront");
        }
    }
}

public class Horse : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int horsePos;
}
```

After that, assign horsePrefab to a GameHandler in inspector simply by drag and dropping it.
This will make your code much better and will fix your issue.  Also for a more correct approach, consider defining horsePrefab field like this to not break incapsulation:

```
[SerializeField] Horse horsePrefab;
```